# EntityFramework - how to get rows that match any of the IDS from another table where the userId matches?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm not sure how to get the rows I need in EF. In SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Recipes] 
JOIN [UserFavorites] ON [UserFavorites].[RecipeId] = [Recipes].[Id]
WHERE [UserFavorites].[UserId] = @UserId
```

I know how to get the userfavorites that match the user id like this:

```
db.UserFavorites.Where(x => x.UserId == userId
```

But then how do I get all of the recipes that match the recipeIds inside of those userfavorites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use LINQ and construct a query:

```
var recipes = from r in db.Recipes
              join f in db.UserFavorites on r.Id equals f.RecipeId
              where f.UserId = userId
              select r
```

or you can use the lambda syntax with navigation properties, assuming you have them set up for the relationships in question

```
var recipes = db.Recipes.Where(r => r.UserFavorites.Any(f => f.UserId == userId));
```

You can, of course, construct the actual query that's described in the first section using the equivalent lambda syntax (since the query syntax is just a language feature that compiles down to the equivalent calls to the extension methods using anonymous delegates), but that tends to be a little more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var recipes = context.Recipes
                  .SelectMany(r => r.Users, (r, u) => new { Recipe = r, User = u }
                  .Where(o => o.User.UserId = userId)
                  .Select(o => o.Recipe);
```

This implies UserFavorites is the intersection table between Recipes and Users

```
Recipes >- UserFavorites -< Users
```